# Gallio and MbUnit in NAnt

Tags: continuous-integration, nant, mbunit, gallio, ncover

I am trying to use Gallio (v3.1)/MbUnit/NCover to run a unit test in my C# code, as part of the build process for my continuous integration system.

I can get Gallio.Echo.exe to execute the tests and output an XML file (albeit it does seem to be checking all .dll files in the folder == approx. 6.5MB .xml file!!), but when I try to get NCover to link in also, it goes bang.

THEN: I tried to use the  NAnt task using instructions [from here](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2009/03/17/Using-Gallio-with-NCover.aspx), such as:

```
<gallio result-property="testrunner.exit-code"   
                application-base-directory="bin/debug"   
                runner-type="NCover"    
                failonerror="false"    
                report-name-format="gallio-MyTestProject"    
                report-types="xml"    
                report-directory="bin/debug">   
                <runner-property value="NCoverArguments='//q //ea CoverageExcludeAttribute //a MyTestProject.dll'" />   
                <runner-property value="NCoverCoverageFile='coverage-MyTestProject.xml'" />
                <assemblies>  
                    <include name="bin/debug" />  
                </assemblies>  
            </gallio>
```

but I get the following error on my command-line:

```
Element Required! There must be a least one 'files' element for <gallio ... />.
```

I have tried to specify the .dll file that I'd like to check, but it still comes up with this message.  Any suggestions are most appreciated!

Comment: it's <files> instead of <assemblies> now: http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/source/browse/trunk/v3/src/Extensions/NAnt/Gallio.NAntTasks/GallioTask.cs

Comment: Marvellous! If you add the comment as an answer instead, I'll make it the 'winner', so to speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<assemblies>` [has been changed](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/source/browse/trunk/v3/src/Extensions/NAnt/Gallio.NAntTasks/GallioTask.cs) to `<files>`